# Java Iterator infinite loop iterates only the 1st item in hashmap

Tags: java, neo4j, iterator

I am executing a database query, and as result I get a HashMap. I want to iterate through all the results, but I infinitely add the first item from the result to the arraylist.

```
QueryResult result=engine.query(query,params);

while(result.iterator().hasNext()) {
    HashMap res= (HashMap)result.iterator().next();
    Node node=(Node)res.get("n");
    results.add(new BusyProfile(node));
}
```

How to iterate through each object and why do I have infinite loop? Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need `while` instead of `if`?

Comment: What is the `QueryResult` class? Where are you importing it from?

Comment: I am using. I just changed to avoid the infinite loop and forgot to chenge when posting the question

Comment: @Mureinik it's neo4j driver

Comment: @AndrewT Make sure to accept an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting your iterator! When `result.iterator()` is called, you create your iterator but on each iteration, it's creating a new one and it continues to point to the beginning - causing the infinite loop.

What you need to do in this case is save the iterator and then use it to move through the collection.

```
QueryResult result = engine.query(query,params);

//Save iterator
Iterator i = result.iterator();

while(i.hasNext()) {
    HashMap res = (HashMap)i.next();
    Node node   = (Node)res.get("n");
    results.add(new BusyProfile(node));
}
```

> Before you can access a collection through an iterator, you must
>   obtain one. Each of the collection classes provides an iterator( )
>   method that returns an iterator to the start of the collection. By
>   using this iterator object, you can access each element in the
>   collection, one element at a time.
>
> In general, to use an iterator to cycle through the contents of a
>   collection, follow these steps −
>
> Obtain an iterator to the start of the collection by calling the
>   collection's iterator( ) method.
>
> Set up a loop that makes a call to hasNext( ). Have the loop iterate
>   as long as hasNext( ) returns true.
>
> Within the loop, obtain each element by calling next( ).

There is a quick tutorial here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm

Answer (score 7):

Everytime you call `result.iterator()`, a new Iterator is created, pointing to the first item.

So create it before your loop:

```
Iterator<?> it = result.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  HashMap res = (HashMap)it.next();
  //...
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you used `Iterator<?>` and not just `Iterator`. Is there a difference?

Comment: Iterator is generic and so is QueryResult. I put a `?` because I don't know what type is returned by the call in the question, but the OP should probably make his code generic if possible and use the real types.

Answer (score 2):

All answers posted before mine explained that `result.iterator()` will instantiate a new iterator each time it is invoked. 
And it makes not sense to create an iterator during each iteration for the same iterator that you are iterating with : `while(result.iterator().hasNext()) {`
.
It is right.

Beyond this misuse of the `Iterator`, you should read the javadoc of the class you are using. It may often help you to create a more effective code.
According to the [javadoc](http://javadox.com/org.neo4j/neo4j-ogm/1.1.3/org/neo4j/ogm/session/result/QueryResult.html) of `org.neo4j.ogm.session.result.QueryResult`, the
`QueryResult`class implements the `Iterable` interface in this way `Iterable<Map<String,Object>>`.

So instead of doing thing more complicated than required, just use an enhanced `for`.
It would produce a shorter and more readable code.
Besides, using the more restricted scope for a variable is better as it prevents to use it unsuitably.
With the enhanced for, you don't need any longer to declare the iterator before the loop. 
It will be used in the compiled class (as enhanced `for` uses under the hood an iterator) but it will be restricted to the scope of the loop.

So you should really consider this way :

```
QueryResult result = engine.query(query,params);

for (Map<String,Object> currentMap : result) {
   Node node = (Node) currentMap.get("n");
   results.add(new BusyProfile(node));
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about the `Iterable` interface as well after I posted my direct answer about misusing the `Iterator` API ;) This *sure* looks like the idiomatic/safe way to solve this in Java and, as such, should be accepted answer IMHO. Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

You should call the `iterator()` method once and then store (and use) the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

Reuse the Iterator

```
Iterator i = result.iterator();
if(i.hasNext()) {
    HashMap res= (HashMap)i.next();
    Node node=(Node)res.get("n");
    results.add(new BusyProfile(node));
}
```